# timestamps not working in a deep array of subdocument

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

So, im using nestjs to create a rest api and here is my schema

[user.schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkR4g.png)

[repository.schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ2nU.png)

[commit.schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpI9i.png)

as you can see i also set `timestamps: true` in **repository.schema** it work but when i set it on **commit.schema** the `timestamps` not generating the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field

here is the result that i get

[post result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeaZD.png)

i already google this one but still can't find the solution!

thanks in advance

Comment: i tried add the createdAt and updatedAt field into my schema and it work, now i just wondering why the timestamps wont generated those field even if i set it to true

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.